# How to do user selectable background in own app in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an android app which is a simple home screen. What I want is to create an option where users can select background by themselves. Currently I have made the option but it does not hold the background after I restart or press back button. It goes back to the background what I set in the xml file as android:background. Is there any way out? I heard by using shared preference it's possible. but don't know how to do it. Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have several backgrounds available for them to choose and they select one and you want to simply store the id of the background they have chosen you would do this:

```
SharedPreference sp = getSharedPreferences("uniqueString", 0);
Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("userBG", 5);// this is assuming the user picked your 5th bg
editor.commit();
```

Then onCreate in your activity you can load the SharedPreference again and...

```
int userPic = sp.getInt("userBG", 0); //this will either pull a previously saved number or return 0 (or whatever number you choose to provide as the default there.
```

That's it.
Here's the example from google, in case my snippet isn't sufficient...
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Note that if you're storing an int, you can store the drawable id of the background itself, which saves you one step of translation. You can then just pull the resource directly into the background of your parent layout.